# How to use ros::spin() and values from call back function?

Tags: ros, callback, rosaria, pioneer-3dx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am trying to move my pioneer 3dx robot. I have written a code and it compiles without any error but does not move my robot. I think it has something to do with the call back function of ros::spin(). Please have a look at my code and suggest any corrections :
short term goal is to drive the robot to a point and come back to its initial position [straight path]. I want to get linearposx, linearposy and yaw, so that that I can use them in main function of any other function.

One more thing, when I run the code robot does not because of which all the value I print are zero.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h" 
#include <ros/console.h>
#include "geometry_msgs/Pose.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>




void ComPoseCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg);

double quatx;
double quaty;
double quatz;
double quatw;
double linearposx;
double linearposy;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "Test_FK"); 
    ros::NodeHandle n;                 
    ros::Subscriber ComPose_sub = n.subscribe("/RosAria/pose", 1000, ComPoseCallback);
    ros::Publisher Velocity_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/RosAria/cmd_vel", 1000);
    
    geometry_msgs::Twist velocity;
    velocity.linear.x=0.1;
    
    if(linearposx>=0)
    {
      Velocity_pub.publish(velocity);
     
    }
    ros::spin();
}

void ComPoseCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)            
{
    ROS_INFO("Seq: [%d]", msg->header.seq);
    ROS_INFO("Position-> x: [%f], y: [%f], z: [%f]", msg->pose.pose.position.x,msg->pose.pose.position.y, msg->pose.pose.position.z);
    ROS_INFO("Orientation-> x: [%f], y: [%f], z: [%f], w: [%f]", msg->pose.pose.orientation.x, msg->pose.pose.orientation.y, msg->pose.pose.orientation.z, msg->pose.pose.orientation.w);
    
   linearposx=msg->pose.pose.position.x;
   linearposy=msg->pose.pose.position.y;
   quatx= msg->pose.pose.orientation.x;
   quaty= msg->pose.pose.orientation.y;
   quatz= msg->pose.pose.orientation.z;
   quatw= msg->pose.pose.orientation.w;
   
   tf::Quaternion q(quatx, quaty, quatz, quatw);
   tf::Matrix3x3 m(q);
   double roll, pitch, yaw;
   m.getEulerYPR(yaw, pitch, roll); //getRPY
   ROS_INFO("Yaw: [%f],Pitch: [%f],Roll: [%f]",yaw,pitch,roll);

   return ;
}
```

EDIT:
If I remove this part then also it does not run. I think the problem is in publisher.

```
if(linearposx>=0)
        {
         }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238293/how-to-use-ros::spin()-and-values-from-call-back-function?/) by [Tomm](https://answers.ros.org/users/27284/tomm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2016-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe there is a race condition between setting up the publisher and attempting to publish the message.

For example if you add a 1 second delay between advertising the topic and publishing you should see a successfully published message:

`usleep(1000000);`

You could also latch the topic (meaning it will always publish the last message sent to new subscribers), but maybe not the best idea for velocity commands. Add `true` as the last parameter:

`ros::Publisher Velocity_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/RosAria/cmd_vel", 1000, true);`

But, if you are going to adaptively change the velocity based on the position anyways, you might want to have a loop somewhere inside you're main function that calls `ros::spinOnce()` instead of the blocking `ros::spin()`. See the [roscpp Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B).

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tomm](https://answers.ros.org/users/27284/tomm/) on 2016-06-29**:
Thank you Jacobperron.Adding ros::spinOnce() sloved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So you don't publish unless linearposx >= 0, and your callback won't run without the publisher publishing (linearposx >= 0), and your callback sets linearposx. Am I reading that correctly? Catch 22?

Does C++ automatically initialize global doubles to 0? Even if it does, it seems like poor practice to not explicitly initialize it yourself.

Does the callback execute at all?

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tomm](https://answers.ros.org/users/27284/tomm/) on 2016-06-28**:
Oh that was a silly mistake. But then again when I try to publish the velocity, it does not move.
Thanks for pointing out the mistake Billy.

**Comment by [Tomm](https://answers.ros.org/users/27284/tomm/) on 2016-06-28**:
IAnd yeah regarding callback function,I have checked it before (before publishing linear velocity) and it works fine. I used this command to publish velocity [Rosaria tutorial]
rostopic pub -1 /RosAria/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist '[0.1, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]'